# Why is my check constraint not stopping this null insert?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Can anyone explain why the third insert (labeled **Query Data**) in the below code is allowed by SQL Server?

As far as I can tell, the check constraint should only allow:

- `Code` is null and `System` is null.
- `Code` is not null and `System` is `1`.

My first thought was `ANSI NULLS`, but setting them `on` or `off` made no difference.

This is a simplified example of a larger problem we found in our application (System was checked against a list of numbers - `IN(1, 2, etc.)`). We replaced this check with a foreign key (instead of `IN`)and a new check constraint that allowed either, both null or both not null; doing that prevented the third insert.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[CK_TestCheck]') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestCheck]'))
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestCheck] DROP CONSTRAINT [CK_TestCheck]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TestCheck]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[TestCheck]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

CREATE TABLE TestCheck(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [System] [tinyint] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestCheck] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_TestCheck] CHECK
(
    ([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)   --Both null
    OR
    ([Code] IS NOT NULL AND [System] = 1)   --Both not null ????
)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestCheck] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_TestCheck]
GO

--Good Data
insert TestCheck (Code, [System]) Values(null, null);
insert TestCheck (Code, [System]) Values('123', 1);

--Query Data
insert TestCheck (Code, [System]) Values('123', null);

--Bad data stopped
insert TestCheck (Code, [System]) Values(null, 1);
insert TestCheck (Code, [System]) Values('123', 4);

select * from TestCheck
Where
    case when
    (
        ([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)           --Both null
        OR
        ([Code] IS NOT NULL AND [System] in (1, 2, 3))  --Both not null ????
    )
    then 0 else 1 end
     = 1
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The result of evaluating the current constraint for the values `123, NULL` is Undefined.

- `([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)` evaluates to `False`
- `([Code] IS NOT NULL AND [System] IN (1, 2, 3))` evaluates to `Undefined`

Result is `Undefined`

[Check Constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

> CHECK constraints reject values that evaluate to FALSE. Because null
>   values evaluate to UNKNOWN, their presence in expressions may override
>   a constraint.

You should change your check for `[System] IN (1, 2, 3)` to `ISNULL([System], 0) IN (1, 2, 3)`.

**Your check constraint then becomes**

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestCheck] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_TestCheck] CHECK
(
    ([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)   --Both null
    OR
    ([Code] IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL([System], 0) IN (1, 2, 3))   --Both not null ????
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't put (False) in brackets after undefined. It's very definitely not false.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I know what you mean but I've added it in brackets as to what `undefined` does toward the end result. I'll add this comment to the answer.

Comment: But what you've added isn't true. If the final result of the check constraint is `UNKNOWN`, then it's treated the same as if it evaluated as `TRUE` - that was what surprised the OP.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - <slap forehead>You are right offcourse</slap forehead>

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I have changed my answer and upvoted yours for explaining it right and better the first time arround.

Answer (score 16):

Welcome to SQL's wonderful three valued logic. As you may or may not be aware, the result of any standard comparison to `null` is not `TRUE`, or `FALSE`, but `UNKNOWN`.

In a `WHERE` clause, the entire clause has to evaluate as `TRUE`.

In a `CHECK` constraint, the entire constraint must evaluate as not `FALSE`.

So, we have:

```
([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)   --Both null
OR
([Code] IS NOT NULL AND [System] = 1)   --Both not null ????
```

Which becomes (for query data):

```
(FALSE AND TRUE)
OR
(TRUE AND UNKNOWN)
```

And any operator with an `UNKNOWN` on one side or the other evaluates as `UNKNOWN`, so the overall result is `UNKNOWN`. Which isn't `FALSE`, and so evaluating the check constraint is successful.

---

If you want `System` not to be null, it's clearest to me if you add that as an additional explicit requirement.

```
([Code] IS NULL AND [System] IS NULL)   --Both null
OR
([Code] IS NOT NULL AND [System] IS NOT NULL AND [System] = 1)   --Both not null ????
```

---

It may seem a tad odd the way that this is defined, but it is consistent with the way that other constraints work - e.g. a foreign key constraint may have nullable columns, and if any of those columns are null, there doesn't have to be a matching row in the referenced table.

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that setting ANSI_NULL's was a way to control this behaviour?

Comment: @DaveShaw - I think you need to set it `OFF` which can have other side effects

Comment: @DaveShaw - this is ANSI behaviour, and you've set `ANSI_NULLS ON` (as you should - using SQL Server with `ANSI_NULLS OFF` is really not a good idea, since one day it will [not be possible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx))

Comment: For this current case it does not matter but this claim is incorrect "And any operator with an UNKNOWN on one side or the other evaluates as UNKNOWN". It is correct if the operator is AND but if the operator is OR and you have for example "true OR unknown" then it evaluates to true, which is also very logical, since with an OR it does not matter if you do not know one of the values, as long as one of them is true.

Comment: I must even correct myself here, the claim is not even correct for AND in all cases. If you have "false AND unknown" it does not evaluate to unknown, it evaluates to false, which again is logical, since if one value is false with the AND operator then it does not matter what the other one is, it will always evaluate to false.

Comment: @Magnus - yes, I've been aware that this particular part is incorrect for a while, and been meaning to go back and fix it. I ought to just link to the wikipedia page on three-valued logic and be done with it.